# Can a user find a child page?

Tags: pages, child-pages

When editing a page, instead of the expected content, all the user sees is this:

```
[child-pages depth="1" sort_column="post_title"]
```

How can the user find that page in order to edit it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [*shortcode*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) you see there in the post/page content. It's most likely displaying all the child pages (up to depth 1) of the current page. Shortcodes are very common, but you can't see their output in the WordPress post/page editor, only on the front end where it's generated via the `do_shortcode()` function.

### The "hard" way:

So you can try do the following:

1. Visit *All Pages* (`/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page`) in the backend.
2. Locate the page that contains the `[child-pages]` shortcode.
3. Locate it's child pages (depth 1). See the screenshot below.
4. Edit each child page to your needs.
5. View the shortcode page again.
6. Done.

Here are the child pages of *depth 1* in the *All Pages* table:

[image: Child pages of depth 1]

### The "easy" way:

We can use the following plugin to construct our own custom meta box that displays a list of all the current child pages.

**Demo plugin:**

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: Child Pages Meta Box
 * Description: Child pages meta box for hierarchial post types
 * Author:      Birgir Erlendsson (birgire)
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/158636/26350
 * Version:     0.0.2
 */

function wpse_current_child_pages_meta_box()
{
    $post_types = get_post_types(); 
    foreach ( $post_types as $post_type )
    {
        if( is_post_type_hierarchical( $post_type ) )
        {
            add_meta_box(
                'wpse_child_pages',
                __( 'Current child pages' ),
                'wpse_list_current_child_pages',
                $post_type,
                'side',
                'low'
            );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'wpse_current_child_pages_meta_box' );

function wpse_list_current_child_pages( $post )
{
    $args = array(
        'child_of'      => $post->ID,
        'echo'          => 0,
        'title_li'      => '',
        'post_type'     => $post->post_type,
        'walker'        => new WPSE_EditLinks
    );
    $style = '<style>.wpse_childpages li {margin-left: 15px;}</style>';
    $list = wp_list_pages( $args );
    if( ! $list )
        $list = sprintf( '<li>%s</li>', __( 'No child pages found!' ) );

    printf( '%s<ul class="wpse_childpages">%s</li>', $style, $list  );
}

class WPSE_EditLinks extends Walker_Page 
{
    function end_el( &$output, $page, $depth = 0, $args = array() )
    {       
        $edit_url  = admin_url( 'post.php?action=edit&post=' . $page->ID );
        $edit_link = " <a class='dashicons dashicons-edit' title='edit' href='" . esc_url( $edit_url ) . "' target='_blank'></a> ";
        $output = str_replace( "><a", ">". $edit_link. "<a", $output );
        $output .= "</li>\n";
    }
}
```

where we use `wp_list_pages()` to do all the hard work. But we only have to add the edit links, so that's why we construct a custom Page walker.

This plugin will automatically activate the meta box on all post edit screens for every  **hierarchical** post types.

**Where do I add this code?**

Create this subdirectory:

```
/wp-content/plugins/wpse-current-child-pages-metabox/
```

Then save the code snippet to the file:

```
/wp-content/plugins/wpse-current-child-pages-metabox/wpse-current-child-pages-metabox.php
```

and activate the plugin from the backend:

```
/wp-admin/plugins.php
```

**Screenshots:**

Here's a screenshot of how it would work:

[image: Current child pages]

and with no child pages:

[image: No child pages found!]

Now you can just click on the *edit link* of the corresponding child page that you want to modify.

Much easier ;-)

**Gist/GitHub:**

The plugin is [availabe here on Gist/GitHub](https://gist.github.com/birgire/dd1b31a5f7525ed4bbf6).

Comment: Luckily i found the page on page 4 of 300 items, but that select box looks very useful; which file would i need to add that code to?

Comment: @CeesTimmerman I updated the answer with a plugin, that's also available on [Gist/Github here](https://gist.github.com/birgire/dd1b31a5f7525ed4bbf6). Just activate the plugin and you're ready to go.

Comment: I added information to my answer on where to save it - you don't have to (or should) modify core files for that. I hope it will work for you.

Comment: I added a `?>`, but it works. Thanks. :)

Comment: ok great ;-) ps: where was the missing `?>`so I can update it?

Comment: At the very end of the code.

Comment: hmm ... strange, I never use it. According to the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php): *"If a file is pure PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file. This prevents accidental whitespace or new lines being added after the PHP closing tag, which may cause unwanted effects because PHP will start output buffering when there is no intention from the programmer to send any output at that point in the script."* ...